# Periodic boundary condition and hadronic correlator

Tags: quantum-field-theory, boundary-conditions, correlation-functions, propagator, lattice-gauge-theory

Recently I have been learning about lattice QCD in a self-taught way. I have a question about the 18th page of the following link:

https://www.jlab.org/hugs/Slides/Sufian_HUGS2018.pdf

It seems to me that the correlation function of a particle is usually defined by the vacuum to vacuum transition. However, in the presence of the periodic boundary condition for time ($T$), the correlator is defined by

$<O_2(t)O_1>_T=\frac{1}{Z_T}\displaystyle\sum_{m, n}<m| e^{-(T-t)\hat{H}}\hat{O_2}|n><n| e^{-t\hat{H}}\hat{O_1}|m>.$

Why should one take sum over m, not only vacuum but also other states? The summation over n, inserted in the above expression, is understandable to me, though.

For large $T$, the above relation is reduced to,

$\lim_{T\to \infty}<O_2(t)O_1>_T=\frac{1}{Z_T}\displaystyle\sum_{n}<0| \hat{O_2}|n><n| \hat{O_1}|0>e^{-tE_n}.$

This expression is rather understandable to me, since it is written as the vacuum to vacuum transition (neglecting the inserted $n$ states). To my understanding, the second relation corresponds to the case without the periodic boundary condition. In that case, whether periodic or not affects the definition of the correlator. Why is this the case?